# How Unique is CRC16 Value?

Tags: crc16

I'm developing an OpenSource .NET Licensing Engine.
This engine use *hardware id* (harddisk serial number) as lock and *CRC16* this value to get shorten identifier.

Example value is **MAXTOR ST3100, 476300BE** and CRC16 result is **3FF0**

My concern is how often 2 diffrent value get same CRC16 value, or should I use CRC32 instead ?

Comment: Why hash it at all? Why not just use the string as it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probability of collision between 2 items = 1 ⁄ 0x10000 = 0.00152%...

But if you have more than 2 items, see the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) -- it gets a *lot* more likely:
You just need 300 items to get a 50% probability of collision.

http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLARGE%5C%21%5CLARGE%5C%21%5Cleft%281%20-%20%5Cfrac%7B0%7D%7B2%5E%7B16%7D%7D%5Cright%29%5Cleft%281%20-%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5E%7B16%7D%7D%5Cright%29%5Cleft%281%20-%20%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B2%5E%7B16%7D%7D%5Cright%29%5Cleft%281%20-%20%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%5E%7B16%7D%7D%5Cright%29%5Ccdots%5Cleft%281%20-%20%5Cfrac%7BN%7D%7B2%5E%7B16%7D%7D%5Cright%29%3D%2050%25%20%5C%5C%20N%20%5Capprox%20300.gif

Comment: I think I should add CPU Model to this scheme and CRC16 all individual value before concating it (example 3FF0-D0D0), to higher this probability.

Comment: @F8R: For that, you need 77163 machines for a 50% chance of collision.

Comment: Thx, I think this number quite safe for my Licensing Engine. I don't expect any software that sold over 20K license will use this Open Source project, IMHO, :D.

Answer (score 2):

As CRC16 is a 16-bit value, I'd say that the chance is around 1 in 65536.

Comment: Glad to know the number, I think this quite rare case with Hard Disk Serial Number, :D.

Answer (score 0):

No hashing method generates unique values, collisions being guaranteed at some point.  The closest bet based on your requirements is simply to use the harddisk serial number as-is.

Hackers will crack it easily though.

Comment: This value is from Hardisk serial number (HDSN), and if hacker can manipulate HDSN, using naked HDSN is useless too, :D. But I'm using RSA 2048 for license signature verification, HDSN only for locking the license into machine.